# Iterating an array with a local mutable copy in Rust

Tags: rust

I am a Rust beginner and could not find anything regarding this in the docs. Would appreciate any help.
The following loop in C++

```cpp
for (const int i : {1,2,3,4,5})
  cout << i;
```

roughly translates into

```rust
for &i in &[1,2,3,4,5] {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Is there a way to write the equivalent of

```cpp
for (int i : {1,2,3,4,5}) {
  i += 1;
  cout << i;
}
```

in Rust concisely? Namely is there a shorthand to make a local mutable copy of whats being iterated over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

The left part of a `for` is a pattern.

There are three patterns that you need for this:

- `&pat` as you already have, because you get references when iterating.
- `mut name` that creates a mutable binding. You are currently using the `name` pattern, which creates an immutable binding, arguably the simplest of the patterns!
- `(pat)` where parenthesis can be used to disambiguate sub-patterns.

Patterns can be combined together which would give:

```
for &(mut i) in &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
    i += 1;
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=246d9259bab110ec3c6b0a134a5eced4))

The parenthesis are necessary to disambiguate from another pattern `&mut pat` which means binding a mutable reference, which isn't the same.

However, I wouldn't say this is very common, and a more common way would be to do this is two steps:

```
for &i in &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
    let i = i + 1;
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

or

```
for &i in &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
    let mut i = i; // rebind as mutable
    i += 1;
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Comment: I prefer this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea20ce1818c495e8cfdf212805f60f61

Comment: @mcarton Thank you, really appreciate this answer. Thanks for mentioning the more common ways of doing this, it really helps!

Comment: @Stargateur That code mutates the original array, which is a little different than the c++ code and what want to achieve

Comment: @boinkboink Oh indeed that odd, well in this case I would prefer this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09e6e277be2b2db4e0563de386c980e7.

Comment: For any non-trivial example, I probably would have stuck a `map` in there too actually.

Comment: It is a pity that rust generates a warning, suggesting to remove the parentheses in `&(mut i)` which are not redundant. Well, at least we have `#[allow(unused_parens)]`.